# Which Mobile Wallet support *data* field?

Tags: wallets, qrcode

Referring to this link [ERC: Standard URI scheme with metadata, value and byte code #67](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/67)

Since it was proposed in 2016, may I know if there is any mobile wallet that can scan QR code with these 4 fields?

> **address, value, gas, data**

Especially the data field. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A transaction QR code scanning is not a good approach for dApps. Nowadays there are a plenty of wallets through new WalletConnect interface which allows a wallet to connect to a website and then make several transactions with mobile approvals:

https://walletconnect.org/apps

Users do not need to fill this field manually, but web3.js client library does it form them.

Comment: The Web3.js works on the web wallet. Does it works with Mobile Wallet?

Comment: Yes, please see WalletConnect demo.

Comment: I took a brief look, seems like there is a need to pay Infura. I do not understand why using QR Code is not a good approach other than it is totally free.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. You do not need to pay Infura. You can use any Ethereum node, even run one yourself.

Comment: Please hop in WalletConnect Telegram chat and we can give more guidance https://t.me/walletconnect

Comment: Thanks Mikko, will do so later.

Comment: I tried to take a closer look, WalletConnect is kind of over engineered for application like "Scan QR code to pay for bus fare" on a bus. Anyway, this seems like the only viable option for now. Thanks.

Comment: It is a complex. But some internal complexity for the simple use case: you might want to pay with a stablecoin - that is ERC-20 smart contract - immediately there is so much data that is difficult to pack to a single QR code. Or even giving an option to choose the currency.